# How to parse this Complex JObject in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, parsing, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am using ASP.NET (Azure Mobile App Services) for my Xamarin Forms App as middleware between LogicApp and my Xamarin Forms for security purposes.  When I'm not using middleware it returns simple JSON data and I can parse it, but when I'm using the middleware it will return some complex JSON data that I can't parse.  Whenever I try to parse it using `JObject.Parse` the app will force close immediately.  Here is the example the data I get that I want to parse:

```
{\"Table1\":[{\"Point\":223,\"AmountPoint\":89200.0}]}
```

Any idea how to parse it in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: if using JObject.Parse causes a crash, then wrap it in a try/catch to figure out what the exception is

Comment: so actually i can using JObject.Parse to parse that complex json data ? and the error is in my code not the way i parse it ? because for a second i think "maybe this is not the method to parse this json data, maybe there is another way to parse it " because i never ecounter this type of json data before

Comment: Are there actually backslashes in your JSON like that, or are you looking at in a debugger?

Comment: yes there a blacksases in there, before i'm using middleware and get the data directly through logic app the data that i get is like this  {Table1 : {Point: 223 ,  AmountPoint: 89200.0} } and im able to parse it using JObject.Parse  but its change somehow when im using middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware must be double-serializing the JSON.  You will need to parse it twice then-- once to get the "real" JSON, and then a second time to get the actual data.  If you were using `JObject.Parse` before, you should be able to do it like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse((string)JToken.Parse(doubleSerializedJson));
```