# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I got an issue that is similar to [Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409814/error-reading-jobject-from-jsonreader-current-jsonreader-item-is-not-an-object)

I show you my json

```
var json = "{ 
  \"0\": { 
    \"url\": \"\", 
    \"name\": \"\"
  }
}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(json); // get error
```

When I try to parse this string using `JObject.Parse();` I got the following error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer

I can't use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(json);` because I can't create a class with this structure.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: What's the class? Provide more code and details.

Comment: I've not created class because I can't with the structure, try in this link https://json2csharp.com/. Which details you want ? I put an update, I hope it will help you

Comment: Works for me. Specifically, the following c#: `var json = "{ \"0\": { \"url\": \"\", \"name\": \"\"} }"; var obj = JObject.Parse(json);` makes a `JObject` with key `"0"` and value that is another JObject containing two keys with values. Therefore, something about what you are doing isn't quite the same as what you show. Maybe `Debug.WriteLine(json);` to see exactly what you have.

Comment: NOTE: I tested on an Android emulator, using latest VS 2022 and latest Newtonsoft.json nuget. How did you test?

Comment: I tested with real device and got error from appcenter : https://appcenter.ms/apps

Comment: refer to this case:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179382/how-to-parse-this-complex-jobject-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm gonna try @Adrain Zhu -MSFT